# Laplace Transform of $f(t)=c$: Evaluating the limit of a product of functions, when one function has a complex number?

Tags: limits, laplace-transform

When evaluating the Laplace Transform of $f(t)=c$, assuming $s$ is some complex number $s=\sigma+i\omega$

$F(s)=\frac cs(1-\lim_{T\to \infty}e^{-\sigma T}(\cos\omega T-i\sin\omega T)$

I can see that $e^{-\sigma T}$ will approach zero as long as $\sigma>0$ but $\cos\omega T-i\sin\omega T$ doesn't approach anything.

I know that the limit of $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is the limit of $f(x)$ multiplied by the limit of $g(x)$, provided that both functions have a limit.

But in this case, only one of them has a limit (equal to zero), while the other is undefined.

My textbook says that $\lim_{T\to \infty}e^{-\sigma T}(\cos\omega T-i\sin\omega T)=0$  provided that $\sigma >0$

I don't have experience evaluating limits like this, what am I missing?

Comment: $\cos (\omega T)$ and $\sin (\omega T)$ are bounded an  $e^{-\sigma T} \to 0$,.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|e^{xi}| = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ and $|e^a| = e^a$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$,
$$|e^{-\sigma T}e^{-\omega T i}| = |e^{-\sigma T}||e^{-\omega T i}| = e^{-\sigma T}$$ and this shows that the distance from $e^{-\sigma T}e^{-\omega T i}$ to the origin can be make arbitrarily small taking $T$ sufficiently large.